# How to pause task running on a worker thread and wait for user input?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, async-await

If I have a task running on a worker thread and when it finds something wrong, is it possible to pause and wait for the user to intervene before continuing?

For example, suppose I have something like this:

```
async void btnStartTask_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    await Task.Run(() => LongRunningTask());
}

// CPU-bound
bool LongRunningTask()
{
    // Establish some connection here.

    // Do some work here.

    List<Foo> incorrectValues = GetIncorrectValuesFromAbove();

    if (incorrectValues.Count > 0)
    {
        // Here, I want to present the "incorrect values" to the user (on the UI thread)
        // and let them select whether to modify a value, ignore it, or abort.
        var confirmedValues = WaitForUserInput(incorrectValues);
    }
    
    // Continue processing.
}
```

Is it possible to substitute `WaitForUserInput()` with something that runs on the UI thread, waits for the user's intervention, and then acts accordingly? If so, how? I'm not looking for complete code or anything; if someone could point me in the right direction, I would be grateful.

Comment: You need some sort of signaling, I'd probably have used a `TaskCompletionSource` that is created on `WaitForUserInput` and completed on the event generated by input. 
 https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.taskcompletionsource-1?view=netcore-3.1

Comment: Additionally, I'd have expected your long running task to be asynchronous because it handles connections. Or does the library you use not support asynchronous network calls?

Comment: @Jason Wouldn't `TaskCompletionSource.SetResult()` mark the task as completed though? How to continue the task later after getting user input? _"does the library you use not support asynchronous network calls"_ It doesn't. Plus, the method also handles other CPU-bound operations.

Comment: What kind of intervention is expected to be the user's intervention? Will you have to wait for a `Button.Click` event or something?

Comment: @TheodorZoulias I will display a dialog and ask the user to review the incorrect values.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What you're looking for is almost exactly `Progress<T>`, except you want to have the thing that reports progress get a task back with some information that they can await and inspect the results of.  [Creating `Progress<T>` yourself isn't terribly hard.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20430698/1159478), and you can reasonably easily adapt it so that it computes a result.

```
public interface IPrompt<TResult, TInput>
{
    Task<TResult> Prompt(TInput input);
}

public class Prompt<TResult, TInput> : IPrompt<TResult, TInput>
{
    private SynchronizationContext context;
    private Func<TInput, Task<TResult>> prompt;
    public Prompt(Func<TInput, Task<TResult>> prompt)
    {
        context = SynchronizationContext.Current ?? new SynchronizationContext();
        this.prompt += prompt;
    }

    Task<TResult> IPrompt<TResult, TInput>.Prompt(TInput input)
    {
        var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<TResult>();
        context.Post(data => prompt((TInput)data)
            .ContinueWith(task =>
            {
                if (task.IsCanceled)
                    tcs.TrySetCanceled();
                if (task.IsFaulted)
                    tcs.TrySetException(task.Exception.InnerExceptions);
                else
                    tcs.TrySetResult(task.Result);
            }), input);
        return tcs.Task;
    }
}
```

Now you simply need to have an asynchronous method that accepts the data from the long running process and returns a task with whatever the user interface's response is.

Comment: Based on an OP's [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64090710/how-to-pause-task-running-on-a-worker-thread-and-wait-for-user-input#comment113335413_64090710), the `prompt` delegate needs not to be asynchronous. Which would make the `Prompt` class much simpler. Just [`Send`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.synchronizationcontext.send)ing a synchronous action to the sync context should be enough.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias Since one should not be blocking the UI thread, waiting for user input generally needs to be asynchronous. In the rare case that they already have a value without needing to block the UI thread, they can synchronously return the value in a wrapped task anyway, but it takes so little work to handle the far more common case of waiting on UI being asynchronous that it's worth the handful of not very complex lines of code needed to support it. And if the non-UI operation needs to be synchronous it can just wait on the task, easy enough to do if it's needed.  The reverse isn't easy.

Comment: This is great!! I was indeed thinking of using a [modified version](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32935021/13485806) of `Progress<T>` with sync reporting as a hacky workaround but this is much cleaner. Thank you!

Comment: Yeap, I agree. The problem is that there is no built-in support for making an asynchronous method out of UI-generated events. So if for example you wanted to await a `Button.Click` event, you would need a custom `ButtonClickAsync` wrapper, which means even more `TaskCompletionSource`s, which would probably be too much. In that case I would consider scraping the whole "wait for user input" idea, and going instead with a two-stage background processing API.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias Sure, if it's feasible to just break the background work up like that, then yeah, that would be fine too.  Without knowing what the work is, it's hard to say if that would be feasible or preferable, particularly if there are numerous points in the work at which it needs to stop and get user feedback, and "picking up where it left off" might be easy or hard depending on what the actual work is.  The advantage of this is you can pass the Prompt object through many layers of abstraction.

Comment: Any chance of an example in the OP context about how this solution would actually be implemented? That would be really helpful if you had a moment, I don't quite understand

Answer (score 2):

You can use `TaskCompletionSource` to generate a task that can be awaited within the `LongRunningTask`.

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApp5
{
    class Program
    {
        private static event Action<string> Input;
        public static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            var inputTask = InputTask();
            var longRunningTask = Task.Run(() => LongRunningTask());

            await Task.WhenAll(inputTask, longRunningTask);
        }

        private static async Task InputTask()
        {
            await Task.Yield();
            while(true)
            {
                var input = await Console.In.ReadLineAsync();
                Input?.Invoke(input);
            }
        }

        static async Task<bool> LongRunningTask()
        {
            SomeExpensiveCall();

            var incorrectValues = GetIncorrectValuesFromAbove();

            if (incorrectValues.Count > 0)
            {
                var confirmedValues = await WaitForUserInput(incorrectValues).ConfigureAwait(false);
            }

            // Continue processing.
            return true;
        }

        private static void SomeExpensiveCall()
        {
        }

        private static Task<string> WaitForUserInput(IList<string> incorrectValues)
        {
            var taskCompletionSource = new TaskCompletionSource<string>();
            Console.Write("Input Data: ");
            try
            {
                void EventHandler(string input)
                {
                    Input -= EventHandler;
                    taskCompletionSource.TrySetResult(input);
                }
                Input += EventHandler;
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {
                taskCompletionSource.TrySetException(e);
            }
            return taskCompletionSource.Task;
        }

        private static IList<string> GetIncorrectValuesFromAbove()
        {
            return new List<string> { "Test" };
        }
    }
}
```

Of course in this example you could have just called `await Console.In.ReadLineAsync()` directly, but this code is to simulate an environment where you only have an event based API.

Comment: Thanks for your help. This looks promising. It's a WinForms app though. I need to get the user input on the UI thread. Unless I'm missing something, that would be illegal inside `inputTask` because it's also running on a worker thread. Did I misunderstand something?

Comment: You can dispatch a delegate to the UI Thread with a `SynchronizationContext` or `Control.BeginInvoke`, maybe show a dialogue and then on user input, complete the `TaskCompletionSource`

Comment: Okay, I will give that a try. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways to solve this problem, with the [Control.Invoke](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.invoke) being probably the most familiar. Here is a more TPL-ish approach. You start by declaring a UI related scheduler as a class field:

```
private TaskScheduler _uiScheduler;
```

Then initialize it:

```
public MyForm()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    _uiScheduler = TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext();
}
```

Then you convert your synchronous `LongRunning` method to an asynchronous method. This means that it must return `Task<bool>` instead of `bool`. It must also have the `async` modifier, and by convention be named with the `Async` suffix:

```
async Task<bool> LongRunningAsync()
```

Finally you use the `await` operator in order to wait for the user's input, which will be a `Task` configured to run on the captured UI scheduler:

```
async Task<bool> LongRunningAsync()
{
    // Establish some connection here.

    // Do some work here.

    List<Foo> incorrectValues = GetIncorrectValuesFromAbove();

    if (incorrectValues.Count > 0)
    {
        // Here, I want to present the "incorrect values" to the user (on the UI thread)
        // and let them select whether to modify a value, ignore it, or abort.
        var confirmedValues = await Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            return WaitForUserInput(incorrectValues);
        }, default, TaskCreationOptions.None, _uiScheduler);
    }

    // Continue processing.
}
```

Starting the long running task is the same as before. The `Task.Run` [understands async delegates](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/task-run-vs-task-factory-startnew/), so you don't have to do something special after making the method async.

```
var longRunningTask = Task.Run(() => LongRunningAsync());
```

This should be enough, provided that you just intend to show a dialog box to the user. The [`Form.ShowDialog`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.showdialog) is a blocking method, so the `WaitForUserInput` method needs not to be asynchronous. If you had to allow the user to interact freely with the main form, the problem would be much more difficult to solve.

Comment: This also seems like a good option and _it works_. Not sure why the downvote. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @ICloneable I am not sure either. Probably because using the `Control.Invoke` directly would be more straightforward than using the `TaskScheduler` abstraction.

Answer (score 2):

Another example using `Invoke()` and a [ManualResetEvent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.manualresetevent.-ctor?view=netframework-4.5.2&f1url=%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Threading.ManualResetEvent.%2523ctor);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version%253Dv4.5.2);k(DevLang-csharp)%26rd%3Dtrue).  Let me know if you need help with the form code; setting up a constructor, using `DialogResult`, or creating a property to hold the "confirmedValues":

```
bool LongRunningTask()
{
    // Establish some connection here.

    // Do some work here.

    List<Foo> incorrectValues = GetIncorrectValuesFromAbove();
    var confirmedValues;
    if (incorrectValues.Count > 0)
    {
        DialogResult result;
        ManualResetEvent mre = new ManualResetEvent(false);
        this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
        {
            // pass in incorrectValues to the form
            //  you'll have to build a constructor in it to accept them
            frmSomeForm frm = new frmSomeForm(incorrectValues);
            result = frm.ShowDialog();
            if (result == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                confirmedValues = frm.confirmedValues; // get the confirmed values somehow
            }
            mre.Set(); // release the block below
        });
        mre.WaitOne(); // blocks until "mre" is set
                        
    }

    // Continue processing.

}
```

Comment: The `Control.Invoke` method is blocking, so I am not sure why the `ManualResetEvent` is needed here.