# Getting user input for a Task running on a separate thread using events

Tags: .net, winforms

I have a long running task that runs in a separate thread. This method reports using IProgress for a progress bar. This method has many points at which it requires user input (data conflicts). When this occurs I am using events (excerpt only), and modifying the eventargs to communicate the results.

```
string taskResult = await Task.Run(() =>
{
    cpCloneManager cloner = new cpCloneManager(_progress.ReportProgress, srcProvider, srcProjectID, destProvider, destProjectID, transferType);
    cloner.SynchConflict += Cloner_SynchConflict;
    cloner.CloneProject(destSubscriberId, hsTypesToCopy, true);  
}


private void Cloner_SynchConflict(object sender, SyncConflictEventArgs e)
{
    if (_progress.IsSplashFormVisible) _progress.CloseWaitForm();
    if (e.SrcObject is Role) ResolveRoleConflict(e);
    if (e.SrcObject is Project) throw new ApplicationException("There is already an existing project in the target database created from the source project.");
    if (!_progress.IsSplashFormVisible)
    {
        _progress.ShowWaitForm(mx);
    }
}

void ResolveRoleConflict(SyncConflictEventArgs e)
{

    if (e.DestObject == null) return;
    using (popRoleConflictDialog pRCD = new popRoleConflictDialog(e))
    {
        if (pRCD.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.Cancel)
        {
            setStatusResubmit();
            e.Cancel = true;
        }
    }
}


public class cpCloneManager : IDisposable
{
    public event EventHandler<SyncConflictEventArgs> SynchConflict;
    public virtual void OnSynchConflict(SyncConflictEventArgs e) => SynchConflict.Invoke(this, e);

    public cpCloneManager(IProgress<(ProgressFormCommandEnum, int, string)> Progress, DatabaseProvider srcDbProvider, int SrcProjectID, DatabaseProvider destDbProvider, int DestProjectID, CloneTransferType CopyType)
    {
        //...

    }
    
    public string CloneProject(int TargetSubscriberId, HashSet<Type> HsTypesToClone = null, bool AddAsNew = false)
    {
        //...
        var e_synch = new SyncConflictEventArgs(p_src, p_dest, dest_subscriberId);
        OnSynchConflict(e_synch);
        if (e_synch.result = Result.Copy)
        {
            //...
        }
    }
}
```

This generally works OK, but some users are experiencing strange effects with the rendering of the winform I use for getting the user feedback. It is something to do with the context the user feedback form is displayed in. The forms are actually devexpress winforms so not sure if the issue is with the winform itself, or the devex skins, but either way it needs to be sorted.

I have looked at other solutions to this requirement, including
[How to pause task running on a worker thread and wait for user input?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64090710/how-to-pause-task-running-on-a-worker-thread-and-wait-for-user-input), but this would require a lot of refactoring and would be more verbose.

My questions are:

1. Is using an event to get this feedback a viable solution, and if so - how do I ensure that my form is rendered reliably?
2. If this solution (events) has insurmountable issues, what is the best way to go about this? An example would be appreciated.

Comment: Did you implement the IProgerss interface yourself? Shows **_progress.ShowWaitForm** your form in the right (UI) thread?

Comment: The IProgress is a bit of a red herring. It isnt relevant to the question, it is just used for message feedback

Comment: Ok. I'm pretty sure, you are in a background thread in ResolveRoleConflict. This will be a ThreadPool thread, not a  STAThread. This could eventually have side-effects in your popRoleConflictDialog.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume, `Cloner_SynchConflict` is a method in a Form. Try to change it in:

```
private void Cloner_SynchConflict(object sender, SyncConflictEventArgs e)
{
    if (InvokeRequired)
    {
        Invoke((EventHandler<SyncConflictEventArgs>)Cloner_SynchConflict, sender, e);
        return;
    }

    if (_progress.IsSplashFormVisible) _progress.CloseWaitForm();
    if (e.SrcObject is Role) ResolveRoleConflict(e);
    if (e.SrcObject is Project) throw new ApplicationException("There is already an existing project in the target database created from the source project.");
    if (!_progress.IsSplashFormVisible)
    {
        _progress.ShowWaitForm(mx);
    }
}
```

You don't really need an event here, a simple callback function would also do. Something like a `Func<[Types used in SyncConflictEventArgs], bool>`, that you pass to your cpCloneManager constructor. Anyways, you should synchronize back the calls into the UI thread. The `Progress<T>` class does this automatically (by using the `SyncronizationContext` cought in constructor).

Comment: Thanks Steeve - I came to a similar solution myself, which was admittedly less elegant :) I moved the body of the handler into its own method and then invoked it.